# Maintain the values in Angular Views

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular.js and i am facing problem in maintaining the JSON feed values in the view.
I am using different routers and when i launch the app it loads the home.html which in turns calls the homeCtrl and make an HTTP call and binds the data using ng-repeat ( in home.html ). If user clicks on the list item to brings them to detail.html ( kind of detail page ).

Now the problem i face is , on the detail page when user tabs the back button - the app goes to home.html and the homeCtrl again hits the webservice and bind the whole data once again. Which i feel is unwanted as the JSON datas was already collected on the 1st time page load itself.

How can i preserve the old data when user move back forth between different views so i no need to hit same call over and over.

Thanks and sorry if its really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i preserve the old data when user move back forth between
>   different views so i no need to hit same call over and over.

If you use the `$http` service to make the requests use the `cache: true` option to use the default angular cache as explained in the docs:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching

Here an example:

```
$http.get(url, { cache: true}).then(...);
```

You can also define your custom cache object through the `$cacheFactory` service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

If you want some more complete with expiration, size limit and other cool stuff try `angular-cache`: https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that you need is create a factory or service;so in this way the controllers shared data between them.
[Here's an example](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)